# Facebook Login Dialog doesn't appear on IE11

Tags: wpf, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk, internet-explorer-11

I have this following code. On Google Chrome and Firefox, it works correctly. But on IE11 the Facebook Login dialog does not appear.

Also when I call this webpage in a WPF application I get following error :

```
"FB" is undefined
```

in line

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
```

Here is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body onload="checkLoginState();">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
 }

  function checkLoginState() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Welcome';
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    testAPI();
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
   FB.login(function(){
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'hello'},
    function(response){if (!response || response.error)
        {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Error occured';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OK';
        }
    }  
    );
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
  }
</script>


<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to load the `SDK` containing FB using `<script src="..." ... />`. Also add a `console.log()` statement in the function loading the SDK to make sure it is called and isolate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using `FB` before it is initialized. Call `checkLoginState()` right after `FB.init` only.
- Use `FB.login` on mouse click, not on load. Some browser block the dialog if you don´t use it on user events.

Btw, a side note: You are not allowed to prefill the `message` parameter of `/me/feed`, it always has to be 100% user generated and you have to go through a review process in order to make `publish_actions` available for every user (and not just App admins): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review